# How can I turn off the x-axis labels in an ASP.NET Chart Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-charts

I want to programmatically turn on/off the labels on an Chart Control.

The chart is for a load of stats, by person, and I want to be able to anonymise it by removing the labels.

Can this be done from the Chart Control, or do I need to do it at the underlying data-table?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes just set the AxisX.LabelStyle to false

e.g

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

I use following code, and works well too.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
```